# Android Studio doesn't display menus on mouse hover all of a sudden

Tags: flutter, android-studio, intellij-idea, datagrip

I'm using M1 Mac Mini.

This problem occurs time to time and I don't know exactly when it occurs. Once it occurs, not only Android Studio but all JetBrains software (DataGrip, IntelliJ...) act same.

If I close all of those programs and restart them, I can see menus again. But it's really annoying to do that every time this problem occurs.

Do you know how to fix this problem without closing the programs?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried updating Android Studio ?

Comment: you can also try from file menu invalidate cache and restart

Comment: @Arijeet Yes I'm using the latest version of Android Studio. I don't think that's the cause.

Comment: @HardikMehta Thank you for the comment. If I just close all the programs and reopen them, this problem disappear temporarily(without using "invalidate cache" menu). But since that close-reopen part is very annoying, so I was looking for a solution that can solve the problem without closing the programs. But your solution doesn't seem like that kind of solution.

Comment: @SJGeeKo, could you file an issue in [IDEA bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA) with screenshots and logs attached?